# Closing a WPF window when responding to doubleclick transfers doubleclick to the main window

Tags: wpf, window, double-click

I have seen similar issues reported but never answered.  This is a major problem for me.

I have a WPF application which opens a new window using ShowDialog().  In the new Window I have a datagrid but it could be any type of object.  When I handle the doubleclick event of a row I close the window.  At this point the window closes but the control in the main window directly under where I clicked recieves the clicks.

I tried handling PreviewMouseButtonDown and looking for clickcount=2 instead of the doubleclick but that had the same effect.  I tried setting e.Handled = true and that also had the same effect.  I tried setting an owner on the window and no change.  I tried modal as well as regular windows and no change.  I responded to the PreviewMouseButtonDown for a single click and that worked but I absolutely need this to be a double click.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is double-click event fires on 2nd mouse DOWN event.  If you close the window as part of that event-handling, you're still about to receive a mouse UP event in whatever window was open behind the dialog.

I think the solution might be to set a flag during double-click handling and on mouse up, if the flag is set, close the window.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i had a similiar problem in our project and its somehow related. We never really fixed it, but now i gave it some more thoughts. And my guess is, because you close the window while you are in a progress of handling the input, this input processing is canceled, your window is closed, but the input request it still remains (because it was not handled before) thus your parent window gets to handle it. 
So this is of course just a shot in the dark but would explain our problem. 
So to give a solution: 
You could instead of close the window, set up a Dispatcher Job using lower priority as Input and just close the window there. It should feel the same for the user but should consume the double click.

Again no guaranty it just sounds resonable in my head.

Good luck.